# Short link to read complete post

Tags: posts, tags, links

I am just a newbie to the WordPress. I was just going through the demo sites and I found a [website](http://jinsonathemes.com/fabs/?themedemo=Olympia). Here you can see there are couple of posts in a home page and just below the every post there is a link.Here I want to know how all the posts are rendered in the home page and when someone clicks on the continue button how someone can read the complete post. So can some one kindly tell me that can be achieved. It may be a simple thing but as I am newbie to WordPress I really want to know how to do that. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

they probably use `the_excerpt();` on the front page. Read the whole thing here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_excerpt

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the more tag in the editor when writing your posts. It looks like this http://alexmansfield.com/wpress/wp-content/uploads/2011/06/more.jpeg

Or you can add this `<!--more-->` when editing the HTML.

Further information can be found here 
http://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Read_More